# DNS issue on new IP range

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-xp

We have decommissioned a DNS server and moved to a new IP range, some of the users inhouse connect via RDP to their PC's but recently I've noticed some of the connections refer to the old ip address when I try to ping them.

So I've gone to the pc and it has the IP address of 10.x.x.x when I do ping -a 10.x frm my own PC I get a response, however when I ping the host name I get the old IP address and obvious unreachable response.

Comment: Try `nslookup pc-name` to see what DNS server is responding with the incorrect IP.

Comment: Coming up with the old address.

Comment: Ok I've found the a record of the PC, its using the old ip range, I've just given it the new IP address, do I need to run flushdns on the server or just allow normal replication.

Comment: ipconfig/flushdns flushes the DNS client cache (even on the DNS server itself) and doesn't have anything to do with the DNS server. Furthermore, DNS records in your zone aren't stored in server memory so there's nothing to flush from the DNS server cache. In addition, if your DNS zones are AD integrated then the change will be replicated with AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you renumber, you need to manage things like this.

It's really unclear from your question what exactly the problem is, but I can guess a little.

I can't tell how your client workstations are getting DNS settings.  However, if it is by DHCP, you need to update the DNS server option on your DHCP server and wait for renewals to happen or trigger them yourself.  If you have manually configured DNS servers, you will need to go in and update all of them by hand.

The other factor here is the TTL.  Hosts can cache DNS responses for as long as the TTL specifies, and often do (especially if they are windows hosts).  So, they may continue to use the obsolete record after a host is renumbered.  One way to manage this is to reduce the TTL while renumbering; the other way is to manually clear caches.

In any case, it's often a good idea to leave the old DNS server in place for a period and have it forward requests to the new DNS server (instead of serving old DNS data); while doing this, monitor it for any DNS traffic at all, and root out and correct any hosts which may still be referring to it.  This might expose other DHCP servers elsewhere in the network giving out bad settings, or hosts with statically configured nameservers.

It's also possible that, if your new DNS server is giving out old IP addresses, dynamic updates are not working on your clients or you need to update your static zone data.

Comment: unfortunately I had to shut down this DNS server, but I did run exhaustive DNS network scanning and removed all of the querying DNS servers etc. So whats the best way to remove the obsolete addresses.

Comment: Put a node at the old address and watch for incoming DNS traffic, or do a packet capture on traffic going through a router bound that way and harvest the source addresses of DNS query traffic.